# Paypal Currency Change in Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, paypal, wordpress-theming

I am using the Cost Calculator Builder plugin on a website. And My client requested to add a PayPal payment method in this calculator with AED currency but in the drop-down menu, there is no AED currency option. And by default USD is selected. Please someone help me to resolve this issue and add the AED currency.

I tried to change the plugin code through plugin file editor but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This list of all currencies supported by PayPal for receiving payments [is here](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/reference/currency-codes/). AED is not one of them. Transactions cannot be processed in AED. The amount and currency of the transaction must be specified in a supported currency, such as (most typically) USD or EUR.

During the checkout in that supported currency, if the payer has a funding source in a different local currency (such as AED), a conversion will be offered to them during the PayPal checkout. However, the amount received will always be the currency specified in the transaction, which must be one of the supported currencies.